# RuntimeException - ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I am using android Google Analytics and Firebase to track errors

the Analytics code has been used from

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

the error is show in following part of code

```
public void trackException(Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

            t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                            .setDescription(
                                    new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                            .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                            .setFatal(false)
                            .build()
            );
        }
    }
```

the error details in firebase are
`RuntimeException - ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo`

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:160)
com.google.android.gms.analytics.StandardExceptionParser.setIncludedPackages ()
com.google.android.gms.analytics.StandardExceptionParser.<init> ()
com.Quest.MyApplication.trackException (MyApplication.java:85)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.SongPlayer (PlayService.java:552)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.PlaySong (PlayService.java:527)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.PlayRecievedSong (PlayService.java:499)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.PlayNormalNext (PlayService.java:894)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.PlayNext (PlayService.java:839)
com.Quest.MediaPlayer.MusicPlayer.Mp3Player.Audioplayer.PlayService.onCompletion (PlayService.java:972)
android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage (MediaPlayer.java:3351)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5910)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1405)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Please provide the implementation of getGoogleAnalyticsTracker()

Comment: `  MyApplication.getInstance().trackException(e);` it is just this

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping an static reference for your context, this is bad and your problem is the prove of it.

Your app has already died and you are trying to do stuff using the context that does not exist anymore.

The fast solution is to change the static reference to a WeakReference and just call trackException if you still have the reference. The best solution is to not depend on the Context, always receive.

If you need to find why your app died, you need to find the logs before the error you are trying to log.